# How to get table name, column name, column describe, column value in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Users:

```
UserID  UserName  UserPwd
  1      zhang     123456
  2      li        455667
  3      wang      332222
```

I would like to get the result like below(UserID='1'):

```
tableName   columnName   columnDescribe      columnValue
  Users       UserName     The user name         zhang
  Users       UserPwd      The user password     123456
```

Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT t.name AS [tableName],
   c.name AS [columnName],
   cd.value AS [columnDescribe]
FROM  sysobjects t
INNER JOIN sysusers u
 ON  u.uid = t.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties td
 ON  td.major_id = t.id
    AND  td.minor_id = 0
 AND  td.name = 'MS_Description'
INNER JOIN syscolumns c
 ON  c.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
 ON  cd.major_id = c.id
 AND  cd.minor_id = c.colid
 AND  cd.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.type = 'u' AND t.name='Users'
ORDER BY t.name, c.colorder
```

Comment: Why would you want to force all possible column values into a single column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select  'Users' as tableName,
        'UserName' as columnName ,
        'The user name' as columnDescribe,
        UserName as columnValue 
from Users where [UserID]=1 
union all
select  'Users' as tableName,
        'UserPwd' as columnName ,
        'The user name' as columnDescribe,
        UserPwd as columnValue 
from Users where [UserID]=1
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40cab/1)

Comment: Requirement is to read column descriptions from `sys.extended_properties`, not to include static values in the query. I'm assuming the column list should also be dynamic based on table name.

Comment: @beargle:Thanks.. the question got edited after I had seen it.. I will try new query

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as tablename,
       s.name as columnname,
       ex.value as 'columnDescribe',
       CASE WHEN s.name='Username' then UserName else UserPwd end from sys.columns s inner join users_1
on object_id=OBJECT_id('users_1') and s.name in('UserName','UserPwd')
inner join sys.extended_properties ex
on object_id=OBJECT_id('users_1') and s.name = ex.name
where UserID=1
```